# more than one tagging form on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a script from http://codecanyon.net/item/dynamic-tag-form/482498?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=RikdeVos . My work requires to have more than one tagging form in a single page. I want to display, say, three tagging forms with different ids: `tags1` , `tags2` and `tag3`.

```
<div id="tags1"></div>
<div id="tags2"></div>
<div id="tags3"></div>
```

and calling the script from:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tags1").tag({
        width: 400,
        height: 90,
        inputName: 'tags1'
    });
});
 </script>
```

now how can I call `tags2` and `tags3` if I copy/paste the script portion and replace `tags1` to `tags2` I am getting the form but there must be a better way like passing name as variables in script.

Comment: In this case there really might not be a better way than hard coding them unless you want to loop through an array of id's at run time which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all the tagging forms by looping through each element in their container.

HTML:

```
<div class="tags-container">
    <div id="tags1"></div>
    <div id="tags2"></div>
    <div id="tags3"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tags-container div").each(function (index, element) {
        $(this).tag({
            width: 400,
            height: 90,
            inputName: $(this).attr('id')
        });
    });
});
```